# Is "0xffffffff00000000" an indication of a mix-up between 32-bit and 64-bit compilations?

Tags: c++, xcode, qt, 32bit-64bit

I compiled Qt in 64 bit. My code is also compiled in 64 bit. I initialize a (pointer) member variable to zero. When I inspect it, XCode tells me that its value is not 0 but 0xffffffff00000000.

Is this a sign of a mix-up between 32 and 64? How might the 32 bit initialization have crept into the executable when both the library and my code have 'g++ .. -arch x86_64 -Xarch_x86_64 .. '? In case it matters, I am on Snow Leopard.

**----Begin-Edit----**

I appreciate finding out after all these years that the standard does not impose the value 0x00..00 when one assigns 0 to a pointer, but this is not the issue in this case.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    const char * c = "Foo";
    printf("Pointers in this executable use %lu bytes.\n", sizeof(c));
    void * z = 0;
    printf("A zero pointer in this executable is %p\n", z);
}
```

If I save the code above in '32_or_64.cpp' then compile it with 'g++ -arch i386 32_or_64.cpp', I get

```
Pointers in this executable use 4 bytes.
A zero pointer in this executable is 0x0
```

If I compile it with 'g++ -arch x86_64 32_or_64.cpp', I get

```
Pointers in this executable use 8 bytes.
A zero pointer in this executable is 0x0
```

If you believe that this does not establish that 0 on my particular configuration should not let me see precisely 0 when debugging in x86_64, please point it out. Otherwise, debating 'null' is a wonderful discussion, but an irrelevant one in this thread.

**----End-Edit----**

Comment: Are you debugging an optimized Release build?  If so, the debugger is probably confused and is looking at the wrong location.  Optimized code severely confuses debuggers.

Comment: No, the build is a debug build. The member variable is initialized by Classname::Classname() : abc(0) {}. When in the member function Classname::myfunction() I ask if(abc) {..} else {..}, shouldn't abc be tested as usual (avoiding to dereference abc unless it has already been set)? Talking about abc(0) assigning abc anything other than pure 0x0000..0000 on some platforms greatly surprises me. Is the whole point of using the precise value of zero not to be able to test whether a pointer is zero as effectively as possible, i.e. without incurring a comparison with some predefined value?

Comment: It could also be a sign of memory corruption. Have you run your program with Guard Malloc?

Answer (score 10):

**Update**: this explanation seems bogus in the light of π's edit. But you might find it interesting anyway.

---

In C-like languages, a pointer value written as `0` in the source code is just a convention for specifying a [null pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_%28computing%29#Null_pointer). A null pointer is a pointer that is guaranteed not to point to any object, and it is defined to test equal to the integer zero, but it doesn't need to have the same internal representation as the integer zero. Null pointers can have a variety of representations, depending on the architecture, or even on the type of the pointer.

The use of `0` to mean "null pointer" is perhaps an unfortunate convention; the level of confusion it causes is perhaps best indicated by the length of Steve Summit's [C programming language FAQ](http://c-faq.com/null/index.html) on the subject.

hexa's comment is, I think, evidence of the difficulty of understanding this convention. The trouble is that there are three ideas to be separated:

- The *concept* of a null pointer: a pointer that's distinct from a pointer to any object.
- The *representation* of a null pointer on a machine (in some cases by the address 0x00000000, but that's not something you can or should rely on).
- How you can *create* and *test* null pointers in C-like languages (by using a *null pointer constant* like `0` or `NULL`).

Here's the C++ standard, section 4.10:

> A *null pointer constant* is an integral constant expression rvalue of integer type that evaluates to zero. A null pointer constant can be converted to a pointer type; the result is the *null pointer value* of that type and is distinguishable from every other value of pointer to object or pointer to function type. Two null pointer values of the same type shall compare equal.

This guarantees that you can create a null pointer using the constant `0`, and test whether a pointer is null by comparison with `0`, but says nothing about the machine representation of the null pointer.

Comment: As far as I know, in C++ NULL is ALWAYS 0. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: @hexa- The literal 0 in C++ stands for the null pointer, but there is no requirement that it be **implemented** as the literal value 0.  All the implementations I know of use the zero value to implement the null pointer, but that does not mean that you can't build a compliant C++ implementation that doesn't do this.

Comment: @hexa - I think the answer explains it pretty well, but maybe to say it slightly differently: yes, in the **language** C++, the #define NULL is 0 and 0 is used to represent the null pointer. But that does not mean that when the compiler and linker get done with your code, that a pointer set to null will have the value 0.  That's what Gareth is getting at when he distinguishes between the concept and the representation of a null pointer.

Comment: @Marc he added all that after I posted my comment. I did not know that the _representation_ as he mentions was implementation specific.

Comment: so, if you cast a null pointer to an integer type, is it guaranteed to be 0 or not?

Comment: No, it's implementation-defined. (C++ standard §5.2.10.4: "A pointer can be explicitly converted to any integral type large enough to hold it. The mapping function is implementation-defined.")

Comment: Please read the part I have now added (between the edit markers) before suggesting that the issue in this case is that OS X is choosing a peculiar value for zero under x86_64.

Answer (score 0):

Perfectly possible that your `this` pointer is not pointing to the correct memory. If your program exhibits other undefined behaviour, then it's perfectly possible that this is just random garbage memory.